# Restrict database tree depth

Tags: sql, database, tree, relationship

Typically when I represent a parent child hierarchy I have a table as follows (I might also add additional depth columns to speed things up), where parents and children are both foreign key relationships to rows from the same entity table.

**Entity Relationships**
composite pkey
child id
parent id

What I am trying to figure out is how to limit the depth of the tree to one.  In other words, if somebody is the parent of a child, how to I prevent that parent from being a child in itself, so it is impossible to have grandparents or even further?

Comment: These are the constraints that you need to implement in the application level and not in the database level

Comment: I didn't like the idea of defining this at the application level because it would be possible to insert relationships into the database that should not be allowed.  I am guessing it is not possible because you must retrieve children from the table at some point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your RDBMS, you can handle something like this in an INSERT/UPDATE trigger. For simply restricting a parent to not also be a child it shouldn't be too bad (although I hate using triggers any more than necessary). If you were trying to limit to a certain number of levels (say 100) then you might start to run into performance issues.

In MS SQL Server you can also use user-defined functions in constraints. There are limits however, so I don't know if it would work here. I'll try to test it though.

**EDIT:**

I just tested this on MS SQL Server 2008 and it looks like it works correctly:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Is_Child (@parent_id INT) RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return BIT
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Test_Trees WHERE child_id = @parent_id)
        SET @return = 1
    ELSE
        SET @return = 0

    RETURN @return
END
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test_Tree_Objects (
    my_id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Test_Tree_Objects PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (my_id)
)
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test_Trees (
    my_id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    parent_id INT NOT NULL CHECK (dbo.Is_Child(parent_id) = 0),
    child_id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Test_Trees PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (my_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Test_Trees_parent_id FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES dbo.Test_Tree_Objects (my_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Test_Trees_child_id FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES dbo.Test_Tree_Objects (my_id)
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Tree_Objects (my_id) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Trees (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Trees (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (2, 3)

DROP TABLE dbo.Test_Trees
DROP TABLE dbo.Test_Tree_Objects
DROP FUNCTION dbo.Is_Child
GO
```